# Scrapy passing param to loader processor

Tags: python, scrapy

There's any way to pass some param to an loader?

I'm doing in that way but i guess that its not the best way:

```
def remove_entry(input_list, deny=[]):

    for d in deny:

        if d in input_list:

            input_list.remove(d)

    return input_list

def parse_page(self, response):

    l = ItemLoader(item=Product(), response=response)

    remove_entry2 = partial(remove_entry, deny=['Desodorante'])

    l.add_css('breadcrumbs','div.breadcrumbs ul li span::text', remove_entry2)

    return l.load_item()
```

I would like to pass deny list direct to remove_entry in the `add_css` method.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked at [Item Loader context](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#item-loader-context)?

Comment: I saw it but i don't realise, now its clear... thank you very much